# How to remove rows containing more than 3 non-ascii character

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to remove all the records/rows where `sms` column has more than 3 garbage values, simply put I want to remove row 4 and 5 in the given below pandas dataframe.

```
id    city    department    sms                    category
01    khi      revenue      quk respns.                1
02    lhr      revenue      good.                      1
03    lhr      revenue      greatœ1øið                 0
04    isb      accounts     ?xœ1øiûüð÷üœç8i            0
05    isb      accounts     %â¡ã‘ã¸$ãªã±t%rã«ãÿã©â£    0
```

**Expected Dataframe:**

```
id city department        sms   category
1  khi    revenue  quk respns.         1
2  lhr    revenue        good.         1
3  lhr    revenue   greatœ1øið         0
```

Comment: What have you tried until now?

Answer (score 2):

We can use [`Series.str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) to count the occurrences of regex pattern `[^\x00-\x7F]` (*which matches a single non-ASCII character*) in each string in column `sms` then use [`Series.gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) to create `boolean mask` and use this mask to filter the rows:

```
m = df['sms'].str.count(r'[^\x00-\x7F]').gt(3)
df = df[~m]
```

Result:

```
   id city department          sms  category
0   1  khi    revenue  quk respns.         1
1   2  lhr    revenue        good.         1
2   3  lhr    revenue   greatœ1øið         0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ascii_string = set("""!"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~""")
for r, j in df.iterrows(): 
  for k , data in j.iteritems():
    total_count = len(data)
    ascii_count = sum(c in ascii_string for c in data)
    non_ascii_count = total_count - ascii_count
    if non_ascii_count > 3:
      #remove row
      df = df.drop([r])
      break
```

Answer (score 0):

The ascii-table only strecthes to 127, which means that if we do a `ord(<character>)` and we get a value over 127, then that is not a valid Ascii-character.

Using this, we can count the number of characters that are not Ascii, and only return `True` of there are 3 or less.

```
df.drop(df.loc[df["sms"].apply(lambda x: False if len([i for i in x if ord(i) > 127]) <= 3 else True)].index)
```

Output:

```
   id city department          sms  category
0   1  khi    revenue  quk respns.         1
1   2  lhr    revenue        good.         1
2   3  lhr    revenue   greatœ1øið         0
```

Comment: Thanks, this answered my question